# Android: custom spinner with corners and custom spinner item

Tags: java, android

I have a spinner with rounded corners. Now, I want to increase the text's size of spinner. So, I created a spinner_item.xml modifying the text size and background color.

The textview it's fill_width. And the problem is that the image that simulates an arrow on my customer spinner is gone. If I put the textview of spinner_item.xml to wrap_content, it appears. But, when I click on the spinner, the background it's white, after the content.

[image: Spinner bug]

How can I put the background gray on the "popup"?

```
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            R.layout.spinner_item, arraySpinner);
```

spinner_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@color/gray_dark"
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

rounded_spinner.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient
                        android:startColor="@color/gray_dark"
                        android:endColor="@color/gray_dark"
                        android:angle="270" />
                    <stroke
                        android:width="1dp"
                        android:color="@color/yellow" />
                    <corners
                        android:radius="100dp" />
                    <padding
                        android:left="3dp"
                        android:top="3dp"
                        android:right="3dp"
                        android:bottom="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item
                android:top="12dp"
                android:right="15dp">
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/spn_arrow"
                    android:gravity="top|right" />
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Do you have the same issue with landscape and portrait?

Comment: this screen it's landscape only.